# About Swift functions, named parameters, and type management

Tags: swift, function, swift3

Suppose I have a function overloaded as such:

```
func doMath(mathOption: String) -> (Int...) -> Double {
    ...
    return average
}

func doMath(mathOption: String) -> ([Int]) -> Double {
    ...
    return average
}
```

Side note: Function `average` itself is overloaded to accept both an array as an input or a list of parameters.

Two questions:

1 - How do I reference which function I am referring to?

For example:

```
let doAverage = doMath(mathOption: "average")
```

How do I specify which doMath function I'm calling? Swift is confused and can't infer from the next line:

If I later write:

```
doAverage(1,2,3,4)
```

2 - How do I name parameters? The original average function is called thus:

```
average(nums: 1,2,3,4)
```

I have to name the parameters. Yet with doAverage, I can't name parameters because of how the return type is defined.

3 - How could I create a type (perhaps using struct?) to simplify this hypothetical code.

Thanks for any help, explanation, or answers you offer!

---

Edit, to clarify 3, here is the expanded version of the situation:

```
func sumAll(nums: [Int]) -> Double {
    return Double(nums.reduce(0, { (a,b) in a+b}))
}

func sumAll(nums: Int...) -> Double {
    return sumAll(nums: nums)
}


func average(nums: [Int]) -> Double {
    return sumAll(nums: nums) / Double(nums.count)
}

func average(nums: Int...) -> Double {
    return average(nums: nums)
}

func doMath(mathOption: String, nums: Int...) -> Double {
    if mathOption == "average" {
        return average(nums: nums)
    } else {
        return sumAll(nums: nums)
    }
}

typealias mathReturnType1 = (Int...) -> Double
typealias mathReturnType2 = ([Int]) -> Double


func doMath(mathOption: String) -> mathReturnType1 {
    return average
}

func doMath(mathOption: String) -> mathReturnType2 {
    return average
}
```

I've used `typealias` to create two example types. Could a type be overloaded somehow to handle both situations? To me, this makes sense in that if the same function is being overloaded to handle different inputs, why not the type? Perhaps this is a naive perspective or perhaps there is a way to express what I'm thinking in Swift?

Comment: Your third question is very unclear. You cannot simplify code that is only hypothetical, without showing use cases etc.

Comment: Hey @Sulthan, thanks for your feedback, I've added my question to clarify it. Let me know if it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to reference the function? Just specify the type!

```
func doMath(mathOption: String) -> (Int...) -> Double {
    return { (values: Int...) -> Double in
        return Double(values.reduce(0, +)) / Double(values.count)
    }
}

func doMath(mathOption: String) -> ([Int]) -> Double {
    return { (values: [Int]) -> Double in
        return Double(values.reduce(0, +)) / Double(values.count)
    }
}
```

```
let average1 = doMath(mathOption: "x") as (Int...) -> Double
print(average1(1, 2, 3))
```

or

```
let average1: (Int...) -> Double = doMath(mathOption: "x")
print(average1(1, 2, 3))
```

I would also advise to to name that type using a `typealias`.

Your second question - you cannot name parameters in function types.

Comment: Thanks! So if we can't have named parameters in function types, is it possible to pass back a struct type or class type whereby the return instance can take named parameters?

Comment: @Babak Or you can return a type implementing a protocol.

Comment: how would you solve this using a type implementing a protocol here?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the function you want done to doMath as a parameter. And use generics so you have some extensibility.

```
func doMath<T>(using op: (T) -> Double, with value: T) -> Double {

    return op(value)

}

doMath(using: sumAll, with: [1,2,3])
// returns 6
```

Edit: It's having trouble with the variadic parameter. 
Another edit: Found a workaround.

```
func doMath<T>(using op: ([T]) -> Double, with value: T...) -> Double {

    return op(value)

}

func doMath<T>(using op: (T) -> Double, with value: T) -> Double {

    return op(value)

}

doMath(using: sumAll, with: 1,2,3,4,5)  //15
doMath(using: sumAll, with: [1,2,3,4,5]) // 15
```

Also, here's a prettier way to write that reduce:

```
Double(nums.reduce(0, +))
```